# Should variables be located inside or outside of if __name__ == "__main__": block?

Tags: python, if-statement, standards

It appears as if variables can be located both inside and outside the `if __name__ == "__main__":` block. In this case I place a file path variable within the `if` block. However, the code works if I place the `path` variable outside the `if` block too.

```
def do_something(path):
    print(path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = '/path/to/my/image.tif'
    do_something(path)
```

Are there any Python standards that dictate whether or not variables such as `path` should be placed inside or outside the `if __name__ == "__main__":` block?

Comment: If the path is going to stay fixed, its usually a good practice to give the PATH variable a global scope.

Comment: It doesn't really matter. Python has function scope rather than block scope, so it's a global variable even if you define it inside the `if` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python is happy with either approach, but if you want to write libraries and
command-line programs that are importable, testable, and flexible for future
evolution, my general advice is to put all substantive code (other than imports
and constants) inside of functions or methods. There are occasionally strong
reasons to deviate from that pattern, but my default approach looks like this
tiny example:

```
# Imports.

import sys

# Constants.

DEFAULT_PATH = '/path/to/my/image.tif'

# The library's entry point.

def main(args = None):
    args = sys.argv[1:] if args is None else args
    path = args[0] if args else DEFAULT_PATH
    helper(path)

# Other functions or classes needed by the program.

def helper(path):
    print(path)

# The program's command-line entry point.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If the path is constant for the program then it can be outside the if block. However if it just an input (and not a part of the program) it should be inside the if block